# Selenium Grid with Linux Nodes

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

We have some hundreds of Selenium Test cases, but we never get the project stable on Selenium Grid.
After a while (running the tests on LINUX with Firefox or Chrome) it is failing because of `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException`

Are there any dos and don'ts for Selenium?
Btw: On Windows Platform, we don't see this issues

(after each test class, we close the driver with `driver.close();`)